# Change to uppercase and change font size when the font is bold

Tags: css

I need this for my blog. I want my text to turn to uppercase when my font is bold. I also want to change font size when the font is bold. I know how to make your font bold in CSS but this one is different.

*The reason:* I have many posts in my blog with the artist names in bold. But I also want them to be in uppercase and bigger to stand out from the rest of the text. 'ppreciate it.

Comment: This depends on how you make the font bold. Also notice that increasing font size for some words will usually cause uneven linespacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS:

```
b, strong {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: maybe you want to add some prefix like `.post b,.post strong`, so it will not affect the entire site, anyway, elegant solution +1